# Identify this large, beige or pine cone-colored squareish beetle and/or the pine cone it's on?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, invasive-species

I saw this large beige beetle on a large pine cone on the ground in February in Hsinchu county Taiwan.

It was about 4 cm long and 2 cm wide and the color was similar to the pine cone it was standing on. Though it was sunny it was cool (15 C) and the beetle didn't really respond when I picked up the cone.

I remember seeing a sign about (apparently) this species in November when hiking so I've attached it as well. I think the sign warns that this is a pest but I can't read it; I assume it is in Chinese.

Unfortunately I didn't remember the poster (from November) until later.

Any idea what it is and/or what the kind of cone that it's on, and what problems it can cause?

---

[image] [image]

### click images for full size

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a beetle, but a true bug. *Tessaratoma papillosa*, to be exact. It is relatively common in Taiwan. It can cause problems if you have a lychee tree, as it is a destructive pest to lychee trees.

Here is an image of this animal:

[image]

The nymphs look like this:

[image]

https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=7887&taxon_id=47743&view=species

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessaratomidae#As_agricultural_pests

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! I really appreciate the extra links. I can see that February was well before the peak observation count in April. Do you know what time of year that those colorful nymphs are most likely to be seen? The Wikipedia article doesn't give any information on the seasonal behavior. I also found it interesting that [this Lychee Stink Bug *Lyramorpha rosea*](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/143912-Lyramorpha-rosea) is often confused with *Tessaratoma papillosa*.

Comment: @uhoh Discerning what time of the year the nymphs are most likely seen is difficult because many people on iNaturalist do not specify the life stage, but it appears to be from April to May. The wikipedia article is actually for the group of insects that it belongs to as the article for that particular species doesn't provide much useful information.

Answer (score 8):

This is *[Tessaratoma papillosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessaratoma_papillosa)*, also known as the lychee giant stink bug. It is a pest for lychee trees, this is probably the reason for this warning sign. See the image for comparision:

[image]

See also this [page](https://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/53273) for more information.

Comment: This is great reading, I'm starting to see why there is [such a stink](https://www.taiwannews.com.tw/en/news/3132866) being raised about them. I'm also glad that I didn't mess with this one; [the defensive chemicals of tessaratomids (particularly that of ***Tessaratoma papillosa*** and *Musgraveia sulciventris*) are notable for being one of the most debilitating to vertebrates, probably a defense specifically aimed against birds. **They can cause damage to human skin and even cause temporary blindness if sprayed unto the eyes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessaratomidae#Defenses)!

Comment: See also [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/38911/18487) for information on the poster. I guess the pine cone is a red herring.

Comment: Can you use your mod powers to check if there was another answer here before? I don't have enough reputation to see deleted answers, but I think there was and that there was some helpful links in it, but I could be misremembering. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Damn, you are right. I meant to clean a flag but it seems I accidentally deleted the answer. It is mainly a repeat of the earlier answer, though.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I was after [this link](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=7887&taxon_id=47743&view=species) in the other answer.