# Identify this black dragonfly with bluish coloration along its flat top, yellow on it's mid-body and green on its head

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I took these photos around noon in late July in Hsinchu county Taiwan. This particular stick in this particular pond is visited by many dragonfly species. I have seen this kind of dragonfly very regularly, in different nearby ponds, they seem to me to be far more active than other dragonfly species in the same area at the same time.

Its body is about 5 cm long and mostly black. However it has light "power blue" to white markings on the flat top surface of its "tail" and "mid" sections and the front part of its body before the head, and it seems to have some smaller yellow bands on the sides of its fore body and greenish markings on its head.

Wings are mostly transparent but are tinged orange or brown near the body.

**Question:** Is it possible to identify this particular species of dragonfly?

[image: dragonfly in Hsinchu County Taiwan July 2020]

[image: dragonfly in Hsinchu County Taiwan July 2020]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This species of dragonfly is *Brachydiplax chalybea*. Colloquially known as **blue dasher**.

[General information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachydiplax_chalybea)

[More information](https://www.inaturalist.org/places/guantian-district-tn-tw)

Comment: can you confirm that it's not this instead? https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/94939

Comment: The colour and placement of colour - blue and it is located on the dragon fly thorax. Also the dragon fly in your link has a distinction of where the colour ends, unlike your image and the blue dasher. Whereby the colour is 'smudged' along the abdominal segments.

Comment: Care to try another? [Identify these two big, beautiful dragonflies in Taiwan?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/95610/27918)