# Why do dragonflies have these special little spots on their wings?

Tags: entomology, anatomy

The wings of several kinds of dragonflies I've seen here in Taiwan all have an apparently special little pigmented spot near the ends of each wing.

Does this spot have a name and a function?

**below x2:** Taken today in Hsinchu county, Taiwan. Note arrows. I've also asked [Identify these two large dragonflies in Taiwan?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/95610/27918)

Click for full size

[image: dragonfly from Hsinchu county Taiwan] [image: dragonfly from Hsinchu county Taiwan]

**below left:** from [Identify this black dragonfly with bluish coloration along its flat top, yellow on it's mid-body and green on its head](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/95229/27918)  **below right:** from [Identify this black dragonfly with a bright bluish-white band around its body](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/94937/27918)

Click for full size

[image: dragonfly from Hsinchu county Taiwan] [image: dragonfly from Hsinchu county Taiwan]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pterostigma is what those spots are. Wikipedia article is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterostigma.

I read the summary of the technical article below.

The pterostigma are heavier than the rest if the wing, and so the insect can glide faster without a destabilising flutter beginning.

The author also believes that the pterostigma contribute to more efficient active flight.

Technical details at:
Norberg, R. Åke. "The pterostigma of insect wings an inertial regulator of wing pitch". Journal of Comparative Physiology A. 81 (1): 9–22.
doi:10.1007/BF00693547.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you very much! btw I've just asked [Why this inertial regulator of dragonfly wing pitch reduces self-excited coupled flapping and feathering vibrations and improves gliding flight speed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/80814/14213) in Aviation SE. I am not sure yet if it will "fly" there or not, but let's see what happens.

Comment: That question "flew" as did this one. Thanks for your answer!